# Github access denied, username

Tags: git, github

Just started working with git and github and I'm having a few problems.

I had set up a github account a while back and started looking into using it but never did anything with it really. I had a username with it but I deleted the account.

I have now set up a new github account.

I have set up a local git repo and committed files.

When I try to push these files to github I get a denied message with the new repository name but the user name from the first github account that was deleted.

Are there config settings I need to set to link to the correct repository and and username.

Answer (score 1):

Delete Your remote first

> git remote remove origin

And add your current repo

> git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git

Comment: Is that any reason why this question not accepted ?